# Xcode 11 : iOS 13 specifically no longer triggers `viewDidAppear` when unit testing

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller

Specifically this used to pass when testing using iOS 12:

```
let viewController = ViewController()
let _ = viewController.view
let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
window.layer.speed = 10
viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
viewController.beginAppearanceTransition(true, animated: false)
window.rootViewController = viewController
window.makeKeyAndVisible()
viewController.endAppearanceTransition()
...
XCTAssert(vc.viewDidAppearCalled == true)
```

No longer passes.
The ViewController's `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear` still gets called.

Any ideas what's going on?

Full example found here: https://github.com/nickm01/Test13ViewWillAppear

Comment: While updating an existing project I also encountered this issue. viewDidAppear is not called by iOS13 devices. This happens outside of unit tests

Comment: @LeeIrvine it must still be called.  It's just now getting called possibly asynchronously in some cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iOS13, there was a subtle change to the ViewController lifecycle.  `viewWillAppear` etc now get loaded asynchronously so for testing some level of asynchronous testing (or waiting) is needed.  Couldn't find any documentation on this and I'm sure there's subtleties but this fixed the issue.